# Accidentally renamed tar.gz file to a non tar.gz file, will my file be messed up

Tags: linux, root, mv

I was trying to move a `tar.gz` file to `/opt` directory and accidentally move it `/root/opt` thinking it was the right place. But there was no `/root/opt`, so the `tar.gz` file renamed to `opt` inside the `/root` folder.

I renamed it back to the `tar.gz` file; will my files be messed up? I'm concerned if that would still be fine.

Comment: In Unix systems, it's entirely possible for a single file to have several names *at the same time*. The file's name is just a pointer to the separate data structure that contains permissions and the contents.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your file will be fine.

Renaming a file will not alter the file's contents in any way whatsoever.

In fact, you would still be able to successfully extract the contents of your compressed `tar` archive using

```
tar -xvz -f opt
```

where `opt` is the name you accidentally gave the file.  Renaming it to its original name would obviously be of help to you for knowing what the file might be.

The name of a file is usually of minor importance on Unix systems.  In particular, it is not the filename or the filename suffix ("extension") that determines how a file's contents is interpreted (although some utilities (often GUI applications) may try to second guess file formats based on the filename suffix sometimes).

Further reading:

- [How are file types known if not from file suffix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207276/how-are-file-types-known-if-not-from-file-suffix)
- [File extensions and association with programs in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71504/file-extensions-and-association-with-programs-in-linux)
- [Why does linux use file extension to decide the default program for opening a file though it's independent of file extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266999/why-does-linux-use-file-extension-to-decide-the-default-program-for-opening-a-fi)